# How to generate a unique link to share for every user that signs up for my website using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need help creating something that works similar to launch rock. After someone signs up to my website, they will get a unique link/url to share with their friends. It's important that the URL is unique so I can see how many people have been recruited by a single member.
Please help!
I am using php and mysql, but I don't know if I need something else. I need help with the code. Thanks.

Comment: You want to count how many frieds user recruited if his friends register too or if they just access your site ?

Comment: You can create the unique link by using base64_encode or some other php encoding function on some unique parameters (such as username + password) for each user

Comment: @yankitwizzy: Please do ***not*** use `base64_encode()`. There's a function called `base64_decode()` that will decode (duh) your encoded string and reveal the user's username and password. If you want to try this approach, I suggest using a hash like `md5()` or `sha512()`.

Comment: I just want to see how many people have been recruited, both would mbe nice though

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much help you need with coding it but you could use the uniqid to generate a Generic ID: [PHP: uniqid - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Then just append that id to your URL something like this: http://www.example.com/page.php?id=$uniqueid

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is use MD5 from member's ID who singed up.

Comment: That's a bad idea since IDs usually small numbers. It would be security-through-obscurity and if you guessed it, it would be super easy to find all other users by just MD5'ing a numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When a user's account is created, generate a random character string (let's say 10 characters long) and associate it with the account by creating a new column in your MySQL table.

You can use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to make a unique ID.

But to account for collisions, you might have to run a loop. It would be a miracle if you'd ever have to run the loop twice:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = ’0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’;
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $randomString;
}

do {
  $id = generateRandomString(10);
} while (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE uniq_id = '$id')) != 0);

// $id is now guaranteed to be unique.
```

Comment: The problem with plain random strings is of course that the chance of collision is much higher as with cryptographic hashes.

Comment: Other way around (hashes are less random than pseudo-random numbers, which are used to generate random strings). But considering the number of possible random strings of a given length and a given dictionary (let's say a case-sensitive mix of all letters and numbers), you get `62^10 = 839,299,365,868,340,224` possible IDs. Good luck colliding two by accident.

Comment: What makes random values random is that there is no way to tell if the same value will occur multiple times. It is not about being as random as possible, but about having a really different value for each user. Good cryptographic hashes will give a different result for all intergers between 0 and a long.

Comment: Which is why I used a check in my code that checks for the existence of an ID before using it. No need to beat a dead horse, sir. A trivial implementation doesn't require a souped-up PRNG.

Comment: I'm sorry ;). I should have noticed your edit. I guess I need glasses then ^.^

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a Unique URL is to use a Cryptographic Hashing Algorithm such as [SHA1](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)
or [MD5](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)  to calculate a unique hash from the User ID. You should store this hash in the users table so it can easily be searched.

Then you can share an URL with the hash applied as a GET value ( `yourpage.com/page.php?redirect=hashvalue` ), and whenever this kind of URL is visited, you can grab the correct user from the database again.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you cannot use your Member's ID like the [SO Member Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455171) or alternatively a GUID.

Comment: This is a comment, not really an answer. Could you post it as a comment and remove this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes and run through bin2hex to get a real random string and check that it isn't already in use (truely unlikely).
e.g.

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20); //may be nonprintable characters
$string = bin2hex($bytes);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php